# Diff function on two arrays, in c++/mfc/stl?

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, stl, diff

```
Diff function on two arrays (or how to turn Old into New) 

Example
One[]={2,3,4,5,6,7}
Two[]={1,2,3,5,5,5,9}

Example Result
Diff: insert 1 into One[0], One[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
Diff: delete 4 from One[3], One[]={1,2,3,5,6,7}
Diff: modify 6 into 5 in One[4], One[]={1,2,3,5,5,7}
Diff: modify 7 into 5 in One[5], One[]={1,2,3,5,5,5}
Diff: append 9 into One[6], One[]={1,2,3,5,5,5,9}

Need code in c++/mfc/stl/c, Thanks.
```

Comment: Why would you want that if you can just re-allocate copy stuff over - it will generally be faster. What is the high level picture here?

Comment: It's a simplify example to outline a database table smart update. I have a several arrays to put into a table; I have the original arrays and the new arrays, need to update the database by deleting only the rows that needs removing and adding rows that needs inserting and changing rows that's already there...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a string matching algorithm, usually implemented using dynamic programming (see [here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Dynamic/Edit/)).

I'd highly suggest using a library that performs the diff instead of implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's normally done with letters instead of integers, the usual algorithm for computing the Levenstein distance should work just as well here as where it's usually applied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm diff library developer with C++.

http://code.google.com/p/dtl-cpp/

Using My diff library, it is possible to calculate the difference between two sequences.

Please see examples/intdiff.cpp about how to use.